# Como criar variável de forma dinâmica?

Tags: java, variáveis

Gostaria de criar uma variável para cada iteração de um for.
Exemplo:

```
for(u=0;u<tamanho;u++)
{
  int variavel[u] = "valor"
}
```

É possivel?

UPDATE

Esse é o código real.

```
  SearchConstraint c1 = factory.createConstraint("metadata#version", f1, f1, ConstraintType.MUST);
  SearchConstraint c2 = factory.createConstraint("regiao_codigo", "1", "1", ConstraintType.MUST);
  SearchConstraint[] constraints = new SearchConstraint[2];
  constraints[0] = c1;
  constraints[1] = c2;
  dataset = factory.getDataset("ibv", null, constraints, null);
```

Veja que tem duas variáveis c1 e c2. Preciso criá-las dinamicamente.

Comment: Preciso criar "u" quantidade de variáveis a cada iteração do for. Não pode ser vetor, tenho que criar variáveis distintas. O código é só um exemplo.

Comment: Se você está colocando c1 e c2 dentro de um vetor no fim das contas, por que nao pode usar esse vetor para criá-las na sua iteração ?

Comment: Você sabe que dá pra criar um vetor usando uma variável como tamanho, certo? `new SearchConstraint[u]`

Comment: SearchConstraint é um tipo em Java? Acho que esse SearchConstraint é da ferramenta que uso.

Comment: SearchConstraint ou é Fluig ou é ECM 3.0

Comment: dá sim @mgibsonbr, eu consegui.

Comment: @RafaelTSCS essa simples informação sua me clareou a mente. Consegui. Transforme em resposta para eu aceitá-la.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por esse trecho de seu código:

```
constraints[0] = c1;
constraints[1] = c2;
```

percebo que você está colocando as variáveis c1 e c2 em um vetor de qualquer maneira. Assim, utilizando o seu exemplo de código, por que não criar essas variáveis já dentro deste vetor?

```
for(u=0;u<tamanho;u++)
{
    constraints[u] = "valor"
}
```